# There was a problem with the program after starting electron packaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

```
error:ENOENT, out\renderer\index.html ont found in D:\lsoft\app.asar
at createError (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle)
at t.<computed> [as open] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle)
at ReadStream._construct (node:internal/fs/streams:66:17)
at constructNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:281:27)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

It says that out\renderer\index.html is not found in the packaged asar file, but when I look at the asar file with ASAR-explorer, out\renderer\index.html can be found.

After restarting your computer, the problem disappears and you can start the project normally

Comment: Soo, do you have a problem or is it fixed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.